# Unirest and connect with API

Tags: java, rest, unirest

I write project in `Java` using `Maven` and to `REST` app using `Unirest` lib.

My dependencies in `pom.xml` looks like :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I want connect with url `https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal`. It is exchange provider and I want get response from provider so I must send information like in [Example 1: Logging in](http://labs.ig.com/rest-trading-api-guide).

How can I do this with `Unirest` ?

I try something like this :

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(url)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .queryString("X-IG-API-KEY", "52d5bc6eee5f2c1775ac4cxz85ef4356c12d23a7")
                .asJson();
```

... but I need also give information abour my `login` and `password`